# Labels cannot be placed in second boxplots in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

[image]If you run the following simple code, you will notice that although in the first boxplot there are labels, this is not the case with the second boxplot where there are no labels. How to fix this? Is it an internal R bug?

I have tried to store boxplots in a working directory just in case this is an R studio graphics problem, but still... the same issue arised even then so this is not an Rstudio problem.

```
df=data.frame("A"=rnorm(10),"B"=rnorm(10),"C"=rnorm(10),"D"=rnorm(10))
for (i in 1:2){
  boxplot(df[,1:2],xaxt='n')
  axis(1,at=c(1,2))
  boxplot(df[,3:4],xaxt='n')
  axis(1,at=c(3,4))}
```

Comment: you need to write the last line this way: `axis(1, at = c(1, 2), labels = c(3, 4))`

Comment: No I have tried that too, I have also tried labels=T. Same issue.

Comment: I can assure you: I just tried again. Replace your last line `axis(1,at=c(3,4))}` with `axis(1, at = c(1, 2), labels = c(3, 4))}` and it will work as expected.

Comment: I had to add a screenshot...

Comment: please, read carefully. write `at = c(1,2)` and not `at = c(3,4)`! Read carefully my suggestion

Comment: Edo is correct. It should be ```at=c(1,2)``` for both plots since you have only 2 labels per plot. The second plot is a not a continuation of the first